# P2SH-P2WPKH private key or revert to P2WPKH

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, p2sh, private-key-export, p2wpkh

Is there a way to get the private key out of an `P2SH-P2WPKH` address, using Bitcoin Core 0.15.1?
If not, is there a way to get the origin `P2WPKH` address to get the private key out of this address?

Comment: You can't go from a public key to a private key, segwit or no.

Comment: I have the addresses in my wallet. It's not from a public key.

Comment: What wallet software are you using?

Comment: 0.15.1 bitcoin core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 0.15.1 you'll need to find the P2PKH address corresponding to the key (it's the argument to `addwitnessaddress` you used for creating the address in the first place), and pass that to `dumpprivkey`.

In 0.16, things will likely just work.

Comment: using `listreceivedbyaddress` makes it possible! Thanks

Comment: I'm confused! How does that RPC help you?